# How to stop thinking philosophically?

Tags: metaphilosophy

My dilemma is that somehow I always get stuck thinking philosophically about things.

One example is mathematics. For some reason, I always start thinking philosophically.

Like word problems; I start thinking **why did I interpret the problem this way. Why did I make these assumptions? HOW do you make assumptions?**

I just get stuck completely on these philosophical conundrums.

Can someone please help me or advice on how I can put an end to this philosophical thinking as it always ends up ruining my day and lifestyle.

Espescially because a lot of philosophy does not have an answer. The question: "Why do we make this assumptions," does not have an answer. "What did the author mean," does not have an answer because we can't know what someone else means.

Comment: A first step would be to delete this question. That, as a joke, of course. I don't really see a problem there. The questions, however, strike me as psychological rather than philosophical. It would be philosophical if you had asked what it meant to be an assumption. What sorts of things are assumptions? What are some helpful ways of thinking about assumptions and their role in argumentation and logic? Why you or humans in general interpret things in certain ways is an empirical matter. Philosophy will not help you make much progress on those matters, I think.

Comment: "How to stop thinking philosophically?" is not itself a philosophical question and thus is not suited for Philosophy.SE. Your question is a question one would ask a psychiatrist, not a philosopher. (Don't get me wrong, I personally find this question quite an interesting one.)

Comment: An easy method would be to spend your time posting here.

Comment: sounds more like executive functions than philosophy

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not itself a philosophical question.

Answer (score 6):

I don't recommend stopping asking questions. For you to stop wondering about the assumptions you are making isn't to solve your problems; it's just to ignore them.

Further, however, I think you're incorrect to think that (i) philosophical questions don't have answers, or (ii) we can't know what an author means.

In the more specific question you've asked about how to frame interpretations of some situation, let's consider an instance. Consider the following.

> Train A leaves Chicago, traveling to New York at 12pm EST at 80 miles per hour. Train B leaves New York, traveling to Chicago at 12pm EST at 100 miles per hour. The rail line from New York to Chicago is 800 miles long. At what time do the two trains meet?

I'm given this problem and I know exactly what the situation is. I understand just what the author is asking me to do--give an answer which is a time. So I suppose that Chicago is position 0, and New York is position 800. Further, I know that the position of train A along the route is given by 80(t) where t is the time in hours elapsed since 12pm EST. Likewise I know the position of train B is 800-100t. To find the time t where the two trains meet I simply need to express mathematically the idea that the positions of the two trains are equal, i.e. 80t = 800 - 100t, rearranging gives me t = 800/180 = 4.44 hrs. That is to say the trains will meet 4.44 hours after 12pm EST. I suspect the answer is correct, because it gives the right kind of answer, i.e. an answer in terms of hours. The *philosophical* point is that I can *know* that I've given the appropriate mathematical interpretation to the physical situation simply by performing the experiment and observing the train from New York go past just before 4:30pm EST.

There are more complicated issues that arise in the philosophy of science in which  any given data won't uniquely determine whether your mathematical interpretation of the physical phenomena are actually correct or not, but that's a more advanced topic.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been <a href="http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17888/discussion-on-answer-by-shane-how-to-stop-thinking-philosophically">moved to chat</a>.

Comment: @stoicfury: What you deleted from the comments had more philosophical content than most of the answers.  Your link above takes me to an error page.  Because of this deletion of my content without warning or notification I am no longer interested in participating in this site.  Could you please close my account?

Answer (score 2):

You may find this link relevant:-

https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/a/9798/5154

> The life drive exists in both plants and animals, even at the cellular
>   level. For example, cells are hardwired to organise molecules; people
>   are hardwired to organise their thoughts, etc.
>
> This hardwired tenacity to make sense of things can overflow too, and
>   because it is so deeply hardwired it manifests as repetition
>   compulsion (OCD). (Difficult to control because it comes from such a
>   basic drive.)

If you want to stop reacting to your inquiring thoughts best just ignore them.  They can arise, unbidden, in your mind, but you don't need to address them.  Let them float away just as they floated in.

Answer (score 2):

I would say the following:

1. Find something concrete that you really enjoy doing.
2. I find that, often, philosophizing arises when the problem at hand is too hard to solve in a concrete manner. So you have to think in broad general terms which leads to (possibly empty and useless) philosophizing.
3. So when you pick things that you want to do, ensure that the problem is not too hard. Of course it shouldn't be so easy that you get bored, but you should know beforehand that you *can* do it.
4. If you get into an overly philosophical mood, clean the kitchen and the bathroom. It will always lead to a sense of accomplishment.
5. Use you hands and legs to do some work. Too often there is too much brain-work and not enough legwork.
6. Do physical Exercise. Take a dip in the sea and get thrown around by the waves.

As to what concrete things you can do, it depends on your tastes and abilities. One thing I've learned from experience is that you need some kind of reward for what you do, whether it is money, enjoyment, sense of accomplishment, praise, or what have you. Moreover you need it in a reasonable time frame - not when you are on your death bed. Now mathematics (of the PhD kind) is notorious for being a subject where the gap between work and reward is tragically long. So perhaps if you are floating away from Maths into Philosophy it is an indication that you are not really enjoying it (I'm sorry - maybe I'm wrong but I sincerely say it from experience), not getting a sufficient reward from it to really want do to mathematics per se. On the other hand maybe you just need to find the right field in Mathematics to work in - these are things you have to find out for yourself. As an example, computer programming has a much lower time between work and reward. Often the reward is relatively instantaneous, because you write something and you get to see the result immediately.

So dammit, take some bold steps. switch fields if you have to, switch careers if you have to and don't be timid. Better to cut your losses and move ahead, just go!

Answer (score 0):

Too much philosophizing may be a symptom of an over-built mind at the expense of the body.  Been there and did not like the feeling. Possible antidotes could be getting sensory stimulation, spontaneous experiences and respecting circadian rhythms.  That may help the mind wean off the comfort of repititive, self validating thoughts.  Hope you find mental freedom.

Answer (score 0):

> I just get stuck completely on these philosophical conundrums.

As a human being you exist within and are part of an external reality, but you are not the whole external reality itself - or at least not entirely in control of the external reality itself (i.e your senses will always be registering things that you cannot control).

So any and all philosophical world views will be "incomplete."  You cannot win this game.  You can only play the game long enough to destroy a human world view you don't like or that is oppressing you.  Maybe this is what you really want to do, and it's fine.

> Can someone please help me or advice on how I can put an end to this philosophical thinking as it always ends up ruining my day and lifestyle.

Learn and accept the value of sensation.  Go out on a cool windy day and feel the wind touch your face.  Don't think about it, just concentrate on the feeling of it.  This is reality touching you, in a way your mind never will.

You also may try getting in touch with your "right brain" functions and looking into doing something artistic or creative, something that develops the "synthetic" part of your mind as opposed to the "analytic."

> Espescially because a lot of philosophy does not have an answer

If you are trying to find an answer, and philosophy is not helping you find an answer, then you are using the wrong tool for the job, and should stop trying to use philosophy to find such answers.

Sometimes "good enough" is a thing - a particular world view accepts something as an assumption because it sees no value in probing further.  And this is fine, if the world view is "working" by whatever definition (bringing happiness, stable society, removing oppression) then there is really no need to go further.

Answer (score 0):

**You can't stop it**, you are born to question every single action happening around you. And you are not the only one, it's pretty common.

**However**. Accept the fact that you can't stop it and just find the answer to those questions, or should I say the one and only answer to all of those questions? Just make up a random answer that you will use for all of those questions.

For example, my random answer is "2 kilo". Now if I ask myself "Why did I interpret the problem this way?", the answer would be "2 kilo.". It doesn't have to make sense, the question itself doesn't make sense.

Eventually it will become a reflex and you will never get stuck again.And you will quit wondering about common questions because you have answered them countless times already.

Answer (score 0):

One very important thing OP should learn is that, for all practical usages we begin by considering a problem starting from the simplest model, and only after that, adding in complexities and other concerns to it. Otherwise we will run into two problems:

1. If mixing everything together makes the problem too difficult to solve, we'd rather not do that because we'd be stuck forever achieving nothing, exactly the problem OP is having;
2. There are always prerequisites that has to be done before going further. It is a fundamental thing laying under the problems you're concerning - there's no point in considering *only* the complexities if you haven't even get the basic problem done. Otherwise it's reversing the hierarchy, which, of course, gets to all sort of problems.

It is also the main train of thought by the scientist, and represented at software programming by the principle "the simplest thing that could possibly work".

Comment: think about it. Why were you making assumptions before I asked this question? Did you ever stop an think why you assumed there is no hole in a balloon being filled with air? In the problem, ""A spherical balloon is inflated with gas at the rate of 800 cubic centimeters per minute. How fast is the radius of the balloon increasing at the instant the radius is (a) 30 centimeters and (b) 60 centimeters?" (Larson Calculus P 153) "? You just made that assumption anyway.

Comment: @Amad27 1. Take a look at [Occam's Razor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Occam%27s_razor). 2. That's a problem, not a question. A problem is supposed to have an answer. So if you find your assumptions not arriving to an answer, the assumptions have to be adjusted. Unless you don't want one anyway. (Also, you have to know much more about the hole to arrive at an answer with it. And that requires much more assumptions, violating Occam's Razor.) 3. You're **also** making a assumption there that we shouldn't be making assumptions. Why do you think yours are right, when they're just equivalent?

Comment: In fact, the assumption "no assumptions should be assumed true" is self-contradicting because if it's true, then no assumptions should be assumed true, and so this assumption too, which leads to a contradiction. Therefore it can only be false.

Comment: thanks for this explanation this is just great. It makes more sense when you say: a problem should have an answer idea. Or do you mean, when you are given something, you are supposed to be able to do **something** with it?

Comment: thanks. I suppose the explanation that problems have answers helps in making assumption s